# For loop causes the application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android

Hi i am using multiple for loop to add view dynamically in adapter class. It causes the application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

When i click the particular item i am calling notifyItemChanged at that time app getting slow. I am using runOnUiThread to update the views in adapter but its still freeze the app for some time and getting the warning message **the application may be doing too much work on its main thread**

Code :

## Adapter Class

```
private void bind() {
            try {
                ((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    mFlowLayout.removeAllViews();
                    for (Element element : elementList) {
                        prepareElement(element, mFlowLayout);
                    }
                    mFlowLayout.removeViewAt(mFlowLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //e.print("");
            }
        }


private void prepareElement(Element element, FlowLayout flowLayout) {
            if (element.getSentenceList() != null) {
                if (element.getSentenceList().size() > 0) {
                    updateSentenceList(element, element.getSentenceList().get(0).getPhraseList(),
                            flowLayout, element.getSentenceList().get(0).getTemplateId());
                } else {
                    addView(element.getElementName(), flowLayout);
                }
            } else {
                addView(element.getElementName(), flowLayout);
            }
        }

        private void updateSentenceList(Element element, List<PhraseList> phraseList, FlowLayout flowLayout,
                                        String templateId) {
            if (phraseList.size() > 0) {
                prepareSuggestions(element, phraseList, flowLayout, templateId);
            } else {
                addView(element.getElementName(), flowLayout);
            }
        }

        private void prepareSuggestions(Element element, List<PhraseList> suggestions, FlowLayout flowLayout, String templateId) {
            for (int i = 0; i < suggestions.size(); i++) {
                PhraseList phraseList = suggestions.get(i);
                if (phraseList.getHighlight() != null) {
                    if (phraseList.getHighlight().equalsIgnoreCase("Normal")
                            && !phraseList.isClicked()) {
                        addView(phraseList, flowLayout, i, suggestions.size(), templateId, element);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!phraseList.isClicked()) {
                        addView(phraseList, flowLayout, i, suggestions.size(), templateId, element);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void addView(PhraseList suggestion, FlowLayout flowLayout, int position, int totalSize,
                             String templateId, Element element) {
            View currentView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_flow_layout
                    , flowLayout, false);
            View indicatorView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_indicator
                    , flowLayout, false);
            TextView textView = currentView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_element_with_attribute);
            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottom_line_black);
            if (suggestion.getIsKey()) {
                textView.setText(suggestion.getPhrase());
                textView.setTypeface(FontCache.getInstance(mContext).getFont(FontCache.Font.REGULAR));
            } else {
                textView.setText(Utils.changeStringCase(suggestion.getKey()));
                textView.setTypeface(FontCache.getInstance(mContext).getFont(FontCache.Font.BOLD));
            }
            textView.setOnClickListener(onClickView -> {
                ((RichElementSelectionActivity) mContext).onClickItem(element, templateId);
            });
            ((Activity)mContext).runOnUiThread(() -> {
                flowLayout.addView(currentView);
                if (position == totalSize - 1) {
                    flowLayout.addView(indicatorView);
                }
            });
        }
```

Please give any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: why not do it in a separate thread and update the UI?

Comment: This is because you are inflating a lot of view in a loop (in addView) method. Try to use ListView or RecyclerView for displaying a list of structured data.

Comment: @pradithyaaria i am using recycler view only but in that recyclerView item i am adding views dynamically.

Comment: @SripadRaj How to update the UI in separate thread ?

Answer (score 0):

- You should use RecyclerView instead
- Heavy Task should be done in background thread: Asynctask, RxAndroid,...

Comment: I am using recycler view only but in that recyclerView item i am adding views dynamically.